# Driver with callback function

Tags: c, embedded, driver, can-bus, isr

I have been working on some embedded software. This software is divided
into two main parts. The first one is the application software and the
second one is some system software. The system software consists of 
set of drivers and RTOS. I have been developing the application part and
I have been using the prepared drivers. Among the drivers there are also
drivers for CAN communication. One of the functions has the following 
interface

```
result_t can_set_receive_callback (can_receive_callback_t cb);
```

Along with this function there is also following definition of pointer to
function

```
typedef void (*can_receive_callback_t) (can_message_t msg);
```

I have problem to understand how to use the driver function. I know
that I have to define some function with following interface

```
void my_function (can_message_t m);
```

I also know that the function defined above is so called callback function.
But I don't know why I have to define the callback function.

Why is it not possible to simply call the driver function without no function pointer passed as an argument?

Does it mean that callback function defined by me "says" how to process the received messages? What is the information which is unknown for the drivers developer?

I meant that the receiving messages are
processed by prepared interrupt service routines but none of the mentioned
functions looks like an ISR.

Can anybody refer me to some good document where
this type of work with drivers is described? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The API wants you to pass a function pointer to a function defined by you. Supposedly your function will then get executed as soon as you receive a CAN message. It will get called by the driver, not by the programmer, hence the term "callback". This is no standardized procedure but something unique to your particular driver. You have to read the documentation about the driver to understand the use. Or if there is no documentation, understand the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) speaking Drivers are supposed to manage the communication on the physical level.

So the driver perform communication device activation, configuration, read, write etc. to manage the HW to communicate on your bus (CAN).

Data link layer is responsible for managing the "protocol" of data sent and received on the bus.

So the driver developer require data link layer developer to set functions that will be called (callbacks) when a specific event is triggered by physyal layer.

In other words, in your specific case, you must set a callback that manage received data based on your protocol with its peculiarity (structure, timings, etc...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer LPs. I imagine the receiving of messages in following manner. Firstly there is a new message in Mailbox. Based on this event the appropriate ISR is invoked. The ISR set some flag which is periodically tested by the driver function. As soon as the driver function detects the flag's change of state, it resets the flag, retrieves the message from the mailbox and invokes the callback function. There is prepared code which further processed the message. Is it right? Thanks.

Comment: It should work, but take note that the invoked function will block the caller function. Moreover, as far as I can understand, you should also take care of flag set and reset: must be atomic or concurrent access managed.

Comment: Thank you for your help, LPs.